# "I want to" vs. "I like to" vs. "I have to"

Tags: english-to-german, verb, meaning

How do you say the following in German?

> - I want to eat an apple.
> - I like to eat apples.
> - I have to eat an apple.

Can you apply the same context to all verbs?

Answer (score 7):

> 1. I want to eat an apple.
>
>    - *Ich will einen Apfel essen*
>    - *Ich möchte gerne einen Apfel essen* (as @teylyn mentions, a more polite form)
> 2. I like to eat apples.
>
>    - *Ich esse gerne Äpfel.*
> 3. I have to eat an apple.
>
>    - *Ich muss einen Apfel essen.*
>    - *Ich soll einen Apfel essen.*

Concerning the last question, if you are asking whether the modal verbs "wollen" (to want) and "müssen" (have to/gotta/being forced to)  apply for all verbs, they do.

Comment: Zusätzlich kann *Ich mag/liebe Äpfel* auch bedeuten, dass man Äpfel gerne isst. Zum Bleistift: "Ich liebe Schokolade, aber Äpfel mag ich auch. Gurken esse ich aber nicht so gern." - Mal davon abgesehen, dass mir schon das englische "I have to eat an apple", aber vor allen Dingen im Deutschen das "Ich muss einen Apfel essen" nicht natürlich vorkommt, wäre durchaus gängig "etwas brauchen" zu sagen, wenn man Heißhunger oder Durst hat. "Ich brauch jetzt erstmal 'nen kühlen Drink." - "Ich brauch was deftiges zum Essen."

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I am trying to find the quickest and simplest way to learn German and this is very helpful.